# Benefits of stretching if you don't care about flexibility

Tags: stretching, flexibility

I don't care about being flexible. I can touch my toes fine because I did a lot of stretching as a kid, I feel like I am naturally flexible. I am definitely not 'tight'.

I also think stretching is boring. Given that I don't care about being more flexible, is there any possible benefit to stretching?

Comment: In what context? In everyday life? With regards to climbing? With regards to powerlifting, dancing, table tennis, water polo?

Comment: Based on your post history I would say that mobility and flexibility are important and you should be doing activist to maintain/develop both (Rings, L-Sit, Isolated muscle movements...) Consider yoga/Pilates for a more "exciting" flexibility workout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research is mixed regarding the importance stretching after exercise. Adaptive shortening of muscles however will cause a problem.

---

### Re-Thinking Movement

Your body moves as a unit in patterns not as isolated muscles.  Think in terms of movement patterns not muscles.  Here's my random example that hopefully makes some sense:

Think of your spine like a fishing rod as it bends and your attached muscles to the fishing rod (you're spine) are all affected. They are all shortening or lengthening and pull from different angles with various forces.

Moving it in any direction will effects the other attached muscles ability to work properly. This throws off your body's entire kinematic chain. If one sides tight your essentially weakening the opposing muscle group -- up and down the kinematic chain.

Janda's upper and lower crossed syndrome shows this relationship of a weak / tight muscle imbalance.

---

http://www.jandaapproach.com/the-janda-approach/jandas-syndromes/

Answer (score 2):

I find that it helps with balance, however, there are two commonly accepted "types," as it were, of stretching, namely "static" and "dynamic."

You can read more about it [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3990897/), but static stretching has been shown to have a negative effect on balance as opposed to dynamic stretching. See [here](https://www.hss.edu/conditions_stretching-tips-athletes-dynamic-static.asp) to read up on these terms in depth, but the main take-aways are this:

> (1) "Dynamic stretching involves active tightening of muscles to move joints through their full range of motion. Functional and sport-specific movements help increase muscle temperature and decrease muscle stiffness. This form of stretching improves speed, agility, and acceleration."
>
> (2) "Static stretching requires you to move a muscle to the end of its range of motion and maintain it without pain for 20-45 seconds. Repeat this 2-3 times each. This is a very effective way to increase flexibility. It must be noted that using static stretching post-event will help prevent injury; however, if static stretching is performed prior to an athletic competition, it may negatively impact performance. Static stretching may limit your body’s ability to react quickly. This may last up to two hours in activities such as vertical jumps, short sprints, balance, and reaction speeds."